# How to skip the lines without showing 0 instead of them in result

Tags: c#

I use:

```
for (int counter = 0; counter <= i; counter++)
            {
              USER.ReadLine();
            }
```

to skip from the lines (the number of lines is dynamic (can change)) but by this method it shows zero instead of the lines that read and showed it in my result.I want to skip from the lines. How can I modify it? BTW, I know there is a `skip` method but i could not find how can I use it.

```
int sc = Convert.ToInt32(txtbx_sc.Text);//sc is an string which is read from textbox
int i=sc*100;
//read both dataset
StreamReader USER = new StreamReader("c:\\1.txt");
StreamReader ITEM = new StreamReader("c:\\2.txt");
//read the line from user dataset and store them
   for (int counter = 0; counter <= i; counter++)
        {
          USER.ReadLine();
        }

          for (int x = 0; x < 1143600; x++)
             {
               for (int y = 0; y < 100; y++)
                  {
                    float lineu=Convert.ToSingle(USER.ReadLine());
                    float linei=Convert.ToSingle(ITEM.ReadLine());
                    c[x,y]+=linei*lineu;
                  }
            }

       }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead creating StreamReader, you may read all lines to array by File.ReadAllLines.
And then manipulating them using LINQ.

Try like this:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("c:\\1.txt");

string[] user = lines
                  .Skip(i)
                  .ToArray();

int userIndex = 0;

for (int x = 0; x < 1143600; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < 100; y++)
    {
        float lineu = Convert.ToSingle(user[userIndex++]);
        float linei = Convert.ToSingle(ITEM.ReadLine());
        c[x,y] += linei * lineu;
    }
}
```

if I understand correctly your question.

Comment: may you comment on the lines of yours @neodim?